# tvOS: Setting adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused doesn't cause focusedFrameGuide to be used

Tags: tvos

I have some `UIImageView`s I want to have the parralex-touch-remote-drag-effect-thing on, but the default size it expands to overlaps some other content in the design. So I want to be able to set the size of the frame it expands to.

Before using `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` I was able to acheive this by doing something along the lines of:

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
        let focusScaleFactor: CGFloat = 1.1
        let scale = CATransform3DMakeScale(focusScaleFactor, focusScaleFactor, 1.0)
        let ty = -imageView.frame.size.height * (focusScaleFactor - 1.0) * 0.5
        imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(scale, 0.0, ty, 0.0)
        imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
        imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0
    })
}
```

But that doesn't have the parallax effect when the user makes small movements on the remote touchpad.

To use `adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` I've overriden a `UIImageView` and its `focusedFrameGuide` property. But the `focusedFrameGuide` property is never accessed or used - as it says it is in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1627692-adjustsimagewhenancestorfocused

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the custom `UIImageView` I'm using now:

```
import UIKit

class MyImageView: UIImageView {

    override var adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused: Bool {
        get {
            print("This is called.")
            return  true
        }
        set {}
    }

    override var focusedFrameGuide: UILayoutGuide {
        print("This is never called.")

        let layoutGuide = UILayoutGuide()

        layoutGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.5)
        layoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 1)

        return layoutGuide
    }

}
```

Why is `focusedFrameGuide` never accessed?